# How to load Chicken Scheme files that contain #><# sharp-sign read syntax?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I can use most [sharp-sign read macros](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20read%20syntax) at the repl, or in a file loaded using `(load)`:

```
#;1> #${ abcdef }
#${abcdef}
```

But I can't use the [foreign declare](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20read%20syntax#foreign-declare) syntax `#> <#`:

```
#;1> #>#include "md5-base.c"<#
Error: invalid sharp-sign read syntax: #\>
```

Granted, there's probably no reason to use it at the repl, but I'm trying to write a program that `(load)`s other sources at run-time and introspects them, and it's falling over when it hits the syntax:

```
(load "/tmp/temp29fe.31217/md5/md5.scm")
; loading /tmp/temp29fe.31217/md5/md5.scm ...

Error: (line 11) invalid sharp-sign read syntax: #\>

        Call history:

        <syntax>          (load "/tmp/temp29fe.31217/md5/md5.scm")
        <eval>    (load "/tmp/temp29fe.31217/md5/md5.scm")      <--
```

How can I `(load)` a file containing `#>` sharp-syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax is only supported in the compiler; it makes no sense to use it in evaluated code.  If you're only interested in using `read` on it, you can probably get away with defining your own override using [set-sharp-read-syntax!](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20library#set-sharp-read-syntax).